# Array return function definition

Tags: c++, arrays, function, qt, return

I've a basic question

I've got a fucntion which looks like this. Instead of `void`, I need to **return** an **array** (array of double with size 3 -  array<double, 3>).

How do I modify the function declaration and definition in Qt?

```
.h

void MainWindow:: fucntion(DATA_T *sample); // how to modify this


.cpp

void MainWindow:: fucntion(DATA_T *sample) // how to modify this
{
     val1 = sample->a1;
     val2= sample->a2;
     val3= sample->a3;

     return {val1, val2, val3};
}
```

Comment: You can simply research _c++ return array_ and find plenty of questions explaining this. Or more generally, research how to return values instead of `void`. If those still leave you with a useful question to ask, then you should also show the declarations of `val*` and explain whether you want to return a copy or to modify the passed-in pointer-to-array - and show what/how you pass that in, etc. Basically this seems like an incomplete and poorly researched question.

Comment: Just replace `void` with `array<double,3>`. Did you try that and have some difficulty? Even if you're not sure it seems the obvious thing to try, and it should work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
#include <array>
//.h
class MainWindow {
public:
  std::array<double,3> function(DATA_T *sample) const;
}

//.cpp
std::array<double,3> MainWindow:: function(DATA_T *sample) const
{         
     return {sample->a1, sample->a2, sample->a3};
}
```